# How can I automate repetitive tasks on Windows 10 GUI applications?

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, automation

New to windows automation - I need to pass around 12000 images through a Windows 10 application the client has specified - downloaded from the Windows store.

I'm a python hobbyist mostly so tried some basic python automation tools I'm familiar with but got stuck v quickly utilising a VM.

Is there a VERY simple method I can use to record some mouse clicks, and then write a "for FILE in LIST: do foo" that will change what file is loaded every iteration?

Sorry if this is super beginner. Tried googling and checking previous answers but got a little (a lot) confused.

Answer (score 1):

How about following code. It will open all JPG files in your image folder one after another.

```
import os,sys, glob
from PIL import Image

for eachImage in glob.glob("C:\\yourImageFolder\\*.jpg"):
    im = Image.open(eachImage)
    im.show()
```